# Access Query for 2 tables with similar data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that have a column labeled `Name`:

```
[CurrentRecords].[Name]
[tbl_vPC].[Name]
```

However, the `CurrentRecords` table has more info on each name such as jr, sr, II, III, etc, but the `tbl_vPC` does not contain that extra information.
Example:

```
CurrentRecords has: ROBINSON, ROBERT E JR
tbl_vPC has: ROBINSON, ROBERT E
CurrentRecords has: ALLEN, DUG V III
tbl_vPC has: ALLEN, DUG V
```

Is there a query where I can find all records in the `CurrentRecords` and all records in `tbl_vPC` that are similar?

Comment: can you define similar?  You are really looking to compare 2 sets of strings against each other.... so you would need a more defined set of constraints instead of "are similar".  What attempts have you tried btw?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `Select * from currentRecords LEFT JOIN tbl_VPC where CurrentRecords.[Name] like tblVpc.[name] +"%"`  May return false positives if multiple people have similar names!

Answer (score 0):

Name is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names.

This is why name parts should be in separate fields. Parsing first and last names might not be terribly difficult because of the comma, assuming EVERY record has this convention and EVERY record has value in this field. Try in queries for each table:

x represents Name field

`LastName: Left(x, InStr(x, ",")-1)`

`FirstName: Left(Mid(x, InStr(x,",")+2), InStr(Mid(x, InStr(x,",")+2)," "))`